# 'pgrep -c' in MacOS terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix, python

I would like to translate the following command, which works in linux Ubuntu and CentOS, to work in MacOS:

> echo $(pgrep -c -P$$)

This is designed to be called from within a python script:

> subprocess.check_output("echo $(pgrep -c -P$$)", shell=True)

and run new jobs within a loop when the number of processes falls below a threshold.

The issue is that the MacOS version of pgrep does not have a -c option.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems a bit of an XY problem. With subprocess, you could probably keep track of children directly or use `ps` If you really want to let any other process that’s sililar affect the loop. Without context of the logic on forking children, it’s hard to offer some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the count of child processes, you can use `pgrep -P <pid> | wc -l` since the output is on PID per line and `wc -l` outputs the line count.